# comparing results from live and test servers in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000

here is my situation.

I have 2 databases which is a live and test database, the live is updated with data and the test database has data one month later than the live.

so i am simulating the work flow which has been processed in the live database and found many discrepancies.

let say i run this query

```
use liveDB select * from tblA
```

the result would produce 100 results

then

```
use testDB select * from tblA
```

the result would produce 300 results

any ideas sirs?

Comment: Use [this](http://dbcompare.codeplex.com/)

Comment: maybe some records were deleted from the live db.

Comment: I'm not sure that I got your question. You just need to compare these two tables from separate DBs? Are they on the same SQL Instance? Can you move them to the same SQL Instance?

Comment: If the test database has data one month later then of course the record counts will be different' What's the problem you are trying to solve - you forgot to state it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The test database is not being added to correctly or items have been removed from the live db.  Check your code where the data is taken from the live to the test.  Maybe you have duplicate entries.  Try the following and see what you get:

```
use liveDB select DISTINCT * from tblA
use testDB select DISTINCT * from tblA
```

Maybe if you are selecting entries from the live based on a datetime where clause, the datetime is not being interpreted correctly.  SQL may be reading the datetime in US format instead of Europe of vise-versa.  If you are specifying a datetime as a string try using yyyy-mm-dd format so that the month and day do not get unintentionally switched around